# React 360: Safari Can't find variable: AudioContext

Tags: safari, audiocontext, react-360, webkitaudiocontext

When initiating a react instance with react 360 in Safari, I am getting the AudioContext error.

I instantiate like this:

```
import {ReactInstance} from 'react-360-web';

function init(bundle, parent, options = {}) {
  const r360 = new ReactInstance(bundle, parent, {
    fullScreen: true,
    ...options,
  });
}
```

window.React360 = {init};

And the error stack in the bundle is this:

1.

> n = new r.ReactInstance(e, t, babelHelpers.extends({
>                   fullScreen: !0
>               }, o));

2.

> this.runtime = new U.default(this.scene, (0, o.default)(t), l),
>   this.vrState = new p.default, this.vrState.onDisplayChange(function(e)
>   {
>                       e ? a.overlay.setVRButtonState(!0, "View in VR", a.enterVR) : a.overlay.setVRButtonState(!1, "No Headset", null)
>                   }), this.controls.addCameraController(new g.default(this._eventLayer)), this.controls.addCameraController(new
>   v.default(this._eventLayer)), this.controls.addCameraController(new
>   b.default(this._eventLayer)), this.controls.addEventChannel(new
>   L.default(this._eventLayer)), this.controls.addEventChannel(new
>   V.default(this._eventLayer)), this.controls.addEventChannel(new
>   P.default), this.controls.addEventChannel(new H.default),
>   this.controls.addRaycaster(new z.default),
>   this.controls.addRaycaster(new A.default(this._eventLayer)),
>   this.controls.addRaycaster(new Q.default(this._eventLayer))
>               }

3.

> "function" == typeof a ? this.context.registerModule(a(this.context))
>   : this.context.registerModule(a)

4.

> nativeModules: [new B.default(this.compositor.getEnvironment()),
>   function(e) {
>                           var t = new T.default(e);
>                           return a._audioModule = t, t
>                       }, function(e) {

5.

> return a._audioCtx = new AudioContext, a._audioData = {}, a._handles =
>   {}, a._loaders = {}, a._rnctx = e, a //////////--->>>Can't find
>   variable: AudioContext

How can I use React 360 for Safari correctly? Is there any way to turn off the audio modules?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a fix for this was pushed to the React360 repo:

https://github.com/facebook/react-360/commit/06918baa2c41156a19d01dbe6cae4996be62e5ca